# How to fire event in each 30 seconds for multiple socket rooms via nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to develop quiz game in which multiple players can play quiz game with each other by making teams. For that I am using nodejs,express and socket.io for connection and for team generation and manage it I a using socket.io rooms.
My challenge is to fire an event that will show questions to teams (socket rooms) in each 30 seconds.

I have already established connection between client and server via socket.io and successfully generated teams and their respected rooms.

here is my code for connection and team generation.

Server

```
global.io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log('conn establish');

    socket.on('requestToPlay',function(request){
        if(request.hasOwnProperty('contact_number')){
            request.socket_id = socket.id;
            GameController.requestToPlay(request);
        }
    });

    socket.on('joinRoom',function(roomId){
        console.log('event fired');
        socket.join(roomId);
    });

});
```

when a user will wish to play he will fire `requestToPlay` event and server will assign a room id with him. After that he will fire `joinRoom` event to join that room.

I want that when a room is created a auto generated process set to that room that will fire an event in each 30 seconds and will provide questions to client.

Is there an way to set an auto generated event on each room on their creation time that will do this.

kindly suggest any example or article link for this.

any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be done using `setInterval` [link for ref](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

you can also use some API like [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule),  [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)

Comment: is there any possibility to set separate scheduler for each room that will start on room creation and destroy after defined time dynamically.

Comment: yeah you can do that

Comment: Hey Thanks, it works for me, But now I have a new challenge. I am writing api for quiz game in node and using socket for firing question to player. Now on game start I have to set scheduler on interval of 30 sec. and in each 30 sec it will fire question to player. But if a player answered with in 30 seconds then I have to fire a new question and the next question will be fired on current time (Time of last question) + 30 seconds.  Is this possible in node-scheduler ?

Comment: can you [ask a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and posting minimal code you have tried?